# codeigniter controller name comes twice in address when redirected

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I'm a newbie in codeigniter so this might just be a basic error but still I couldn't find any answer to this in any other disscussion.. using codeigniter 3.1.7
[image: here is the login page]

If I log in with garbage or correct values it should redirect me to profile page or the same page but instead, it gives me this...

[image: you can see that the Controller name is given twice here]

my Control login function code is

```
function admin_login_view()
 {
    $this->load->view('admin_login');
 }

 function admin_login()
 {          
    $a = $this->input->post('id');
    $b = $this->input->post('pass');

    $flag = "admin";                    
    $attempt = $this->Model->login($a,$b,$flag);
    if($attempt=="admin")
    {
        $_SESSION["user"]=$a;
        return redirect('Control/view_administration');
    }
    elseif ($attempt=="id")
    {
        $msg= "The Admin-id doesn't exists.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_id',$msg);
        return redirect('Control/admin_login_view');
    }       
    elseif($attempt=="pass")
    {
        $msg="The password is wrong.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_pass',$msg);
        return redirect('Control/admin_login_view');
    }                       
    else
    {
        $msg="Login failed.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_fail',$msg);
        return redirect('Control/admin_login_view');
    }                                           
 }
```

I have tried all the listed solutions

1. yes my controller and model file/class names are the same and with caps on the first letter
   [image: names of my controller and model]
2. my .htaccess file contains what the user guide site asked me to keep although I have no clue whatsoever code is written there... if there is something I need to change here please do explain what is it before you give me a bunch of code... :p
   [image: .htaccess]
3. my base path is:

   `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.7/';`

index is set as:

```
 `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
```

my routes file contains:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Control';
$route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`
```

I searched everywhere but no solution helped me in any way... I might be doing a noob mistake herebut please help

Comment: what do you expect - if you use relative paths then this will happen - a possible approach could be `redirect(base_url('Control/admin_login_view'));`

Comment: it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @shreejitpal have you tried my answer?

Comment: it didn't work @desai

Comment: maybe a cache problem try it with a different browser... or clear the cache

Answer (score 1):

You have to do multiple changes in your code:

1) As you have `index.php` in URL, You have to add this also in your `base_url`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.7/index.php/';
```

2) Use `base_url()` and pass your url in it to get correct URL redirection. Also remove unnecessary `return` key word before `redirect`

```
function admin_login_view()
 {
    $this->load->view('admin_login');
 }

 function admin_login()
 {          
    $a = $this->input->post('id');
    $b = $this->input->post('pass');

    $flag = "admin";                    
    $attempt = $this->Model->login($a,$b,$flag);
    if($attempt=="admin")
    {
        $_SESSION["user"]=$a;
        redirect(base_url('Control/view_administration'));
    }
    elseif ($attempt=="id")
    {
        $msg= "The Admin-id doesn't exists.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_id',$msg);
        redirect(base_url('Control/admin_login_view'));
    }       
    elseif($attempt=="pass")
    {
        $msg="The password is wrong.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_pass',$msg);
        redirect(base_url('Control/admin_login_view'));
    }                       
    else
    {
        $msg="Login failed.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_fail',$msg);
        redirect(base_url('Control/admin_login_view'));
    }                                           
 }
```

Comment: Good @B. Desai .

Comment: plus adding index.php to base url is messing with my css links

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
redirect(base_url().'Control/admin_login_view',refresh);
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!! MYSELF!! NOOB MISTAKE!!
solved I actually added 'action=Control/method' to the form that calls the controller function... and changing it to only function name solved it....

the problem was that the control mentioned here was being added to url along with the default controller mentioned in the routes.php

It was a noob mistake sorry for bothering you with such and thanks for all your help
 p.s. a regular redirect function was working in the end :p